# Is my orange platy pregnant?

Tags: aquarium, fish, breeding, pregnancy, reproduction

Hi does my orange platy look pregnant? It’s been that size for a little while now so I’m not sure. [image]

Answer (score -1):

If there is an adult male in the tank , she is gravid( carrying developing eggs). Same is true of guppies,swords, mollies,etc.